# Memory map or physical address of some memory allocated by malloc

Tags: malloc, memory-address

How can I get the memory map or physical address of some memory allocated by malloc?

Comment: Can't you print pointers returned from malloc?

Comment: Could you produce an example (with some made-up addresses) that would illustrate what it is exactly that you're hoping to get?

Comment: actually I am trying to use madvise() for which I require the memory map of the allocated memory as it is not accepting just the address.

I am using ubuntu 11.10, gcc compiler.

Answer (score -3):

```
void *memory = malloc(1024);
printf("memory address: %p\n", memory);
```